# What makes Open Graph checkers unable to detect Open Graph data?

Tags: https, security-certificate, webserver, nginx, open-graph-protocol

[My page](https://lyminhnhat.com/resources/productivity/recommended-software/?utm_source=SE%3A%20Webmasters&utm_medium=Recommended%20software&utm_campaign=Getting%20help&utm_term=post%3A%20Why%20can't%20Open%20Graph%20checker%20detect%20Open%20Graph%20data%3F), after adding SSL certificate, cannot have preview fetched by Facebook or Twitter when sharing the link. I have followed [The Open Graph protocol](https://opengraphprotocol.org/) and include the following open graph tags:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Corner Timer: gently make you feel guilty on time-wasting apps" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://lyminhnhat.com/resources/productivity/corner-timer-gently-make-you-feel-guilty-on-time-wasting-apps/" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Make you feel guilty for your unproductive curiosity" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Lý Minh Nhật" />
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@ooker777" />
<meta name="twitter:text:title" content="Corner Timer: gently make you feel guilty on time-wasting apps" />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://lyminhnhat.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/Screenshot_2019-04-11-11-31-39.png?w=640" />
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
```

However, all 3 Open Graph checkers I use - [OpenGraphCheck.com](https://opengraphcheck.com/result.php?url=https%3A%2F%2Fqu%E1%BA%A3c%E1%BA%A7u.com%2Fbo-suu-tap-tu-dien-chuyen-nganh%2F), [Abhinay Rathore's Open Graph Tester](http://lab.abhinayrathore.com/open-graph-tester/), [Facebook's Object Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fqu%E1%BA%A3c%E1%BA%A7u.com%2Fbo-suu-tap-tu-dien-chuyen-nganh%2F) - say that there is no Open Graph implement. There is one exception though: [Iframely's Embed Codes](http://debug.iframely.com/)

Since all three checkers have problem with this, probably this is not just a problem of of Facebook, as suggested in [FB OpenGraph og:image not pulling images (possibly https?)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8855361/3416774). Nevertheless, nothing changes even though I have tried using html links only, stripping end white space, using `<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">`.

[This person](https://www.reddit.com/r/SEO/comments/csjgav/why_cant_open_graph_checkers_detect_open_graph/) suggests that this may be a server issue. A misconfiguration, perhaps. Do you know why this happens or how to identify the problem?

<sup>Other information:

• SSL certificate: Let's Encrypt

• Control Panel: DirectAdmin

• Server: Nginx

Related: [How to know if a problem is a server issue or control panel issue?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/124684/52079)</sup>

Comment: First `https://quảcầu.com` does not work properly, because the certificate returned by the server is for name `server19.digistar.vn` and not your name. So that would be first point to address as any proper HTTPS client will refuse connecting to it. Second you seem to test with `https://quảcầu.com/bo-suu-tap-tu-dien-chuyen-nganh/` which for me returns a 404 anyway after I bypass the certificate checks. Third, even if I check the main page, there is no meta tags, as the following returns nothing: `wget -O - --no-check-certificate https://quảcầu.com/ | grep meta`.

Comment: I'm getting this issue too, and have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: @thouliha it seems that this is a bug from Facebook. [Here is an extensive list of what I've tried.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57606813/3416774)

Answer (score 1):

It does appear that your server is blocking access by bot sites such as the Open Graph evaluation tools (the site can be access by Google bots such as the [Google Structured Data testing tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/), but not others). I tried it with the https://lyminhnhat.com/resources/productivity/corner-timer-gently-make-you-feel-guilty-on-time-wasting-apps/ address from your tag.

I was able to see your tags when I temporarily pasted your values into one of my pages and then ran it through a couple of the testers.

Comment: can you elaborate more on the last paragraph? What are your pages and the testers?

Comment: I have my own website. I verified that one of my web pages would work with two of the Open Graph testers listed in the original post (OpenGraphCheck.com and Abhinay Rathore's Open Graph Tester). I then replaced my working og tags with the tags from the original post and reran my page through the testers. The tags worked.

Answer (score 0):

Is this your website? [https://quảcầu.com](https://qu%E1%BA%A3c%E1%BA%A7u.com)

If so those tags are not there, so that's probably why you're having trouble with it.

Comment: yes, that my website too. But the scrappers still can't read the correctly installed site. It seems that this is an issue from the server, not the sourcecode