# Is there a difference between server issue or control panel issue?

Tags: server, nginx, control-panel

Is there a way to check if the issue is a server issue, or just a control panel issue? I ask this question to know when one can be accepted to ask on Server Fault, as required in their page [What topics can I ask about here?](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic)

I think control panel is just a GUI for server. So except there is a bug on the graphical display, any problem will be a server issue, even though it is misconfigured via control panel. Is that understanding correct?

Comment: What is the difference between a server issue and a control panel issue to you?  A control panel is usually software that runs on the server and allows clients to edit their site's server configuration.   So the problem could be both an issue with the control panel and an issue with the server.

Comment: I thought control panel is just a GUI for server. I just want to know if that's true to be accepted to ask on Server Fault

Comment: They want to make sure that you are the server administrator and have full command line access to the server.  They don't answer questions about configuring a server through cPanel.

Comment: I see. I can ask the technicians there, or setting up a server for myself. Anyway, would the new edit be clearer?